# No modules named core.management

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

First of all I know that there are a lot of posts like this in all Internet, I tried everything and it didn't work.

Also I have some theoretical questions about it.

I run my installation of Django in a Virtualenv so I type:

```
 sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
 virtualenv --no-site-packages djangito
 source djangito/bin/activate
 (djangito)cd djangito/
 (djangito)easy_install Django // V.1.6
 (djangito)django-admin.py startproject django_test
```

But when I try to run my runserver happen this:

```
 (djangito)root@marcproves:~/djangito/django_test# python manage.py runserver
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
 from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
 ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

BUT

```
 (djangito)root@marcproves:~/djangito/django_test# sudo python manage.py runserver
  Validating models...

  0 errors found
  February 20, 2014 - 09:25:14
  Django version 1.6, using settings 'django_test.settings'
  Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
  Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

It runs with sudo but....Is runing python from VirtualEnv with **sudo python manage.py runserver** ?

I know that virtualenv is a kind of stuff for work with independent packages but I don't know if I'm missing something important.

**I need to understand why happen this**

Thanks at all

Comment: Sure you created the virtualenv and installed django as your user, not as root? (maybe check in `~/.virtualenvs` if everything is in place)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use pip instead of easy install. Every virtualenv has it installed by default (along with setuptools, which contain easy_install) and it is the recommended way of installing packages inside virtualenvs.

```
racech@CONFIG0001:~$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
[...]
racech@CONFIG0001:~$ virtualenv test
New python executable in test/bin/python
Installing distribute.....done.
Installing pip...............done.
racech@CONFIG0001:~$ source test/bin/activate
(test)racech@CONFIG0001:~$ pip install django
[...]
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
(test)racech@CONFIG0001:~$ django-admin.py startproject testproject
(test)racech@CONFIG0001:~$ cd testproject/
(test)racech@CONFIG0001:~/testproject$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
February 20, 2014 - 10:12:51
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'testproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

And as for the explanation it looks like easy_install installed Django not into your virtualenv, but to your system Python. You can check that by creating a new virtualenv with a different version of Python. Make a Virtualenv with undefault Python binary (3.x if you use 2.x and 2.x if you use 3.x as default) by running

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.2 myvirtualenv
```

and then check it by

```
python --version
sudo python --version
```

they should be different. Virtualenv replaces default Python environment only for the user which activated it. Therefore easy_install must have used system Python instead of virtualenv. Maybe you did run it with sudo as well?